# Removing one array from another array / lists Javascript

Tags: javascript

Quick question.

Lets say I have:

```
var specialthings = ['special1','special2','special3'];
var alotoftext = ['randomTextButHereIHavespecial1orspecial2orspecial3']
```

My goal is to seperate `specialthings` from `alotoftext`. So the outcome would be `new var` or `alot of text` (same to me) to be equal to:

```
var newvar or var alotoftext = ['randomTextButHereIHaveor']
```

basically to remove `special1` `special2` and `special3`.

I don't want a remover like 0-9 if the case was numbers, but rather a function that would separate values of one string from another -- literally like this:

```
var new = alotoftext - specialthings
```

kind of an approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can form a new `regex` seperating all the words with a pipe which you want to remove and then use `.map` on the array to replace all the occurences.

```js
var specialthings = ['special1','special2','special3'];
var alotoftext = ['randomTextButHereIHavespecial1orspecial2orspecial3']

var re = new RegExp(specialthings.join("|"),"g");

var newText =  alotoftext.map(el => el.replace(re, ""));

console.log(newText);
```

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm!

Comment: just a quick question tho... I see it doesn#t work if i have special chars, example if i have emojis.. any ideas of a workaround?

Comment: @joe123 use escape characters in that case "\"

Comment: can you implement it in your solution :)

Comment: @joe123 this is not appreciated here in SO. You can post another question describing your problem. Your question is meant to help other people as well but doing it this way makes the thread more confusing. I would ask you to close this thread by marking the answer correct and start a new thread.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks anways, il try to figure it out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` and `RegExp`

```
var output = alotoftext.map( s => s.replace( new RegExp( specialthings.join( "|" ), "g" ), "" ) )
```

**Demo**

```js
var specialthings = ['special1','special2','special3'];
var alotoftext = ['randomTextButHereIHavespecial1orspecial2orspecial3'];
var output = alotoftext.map( s => s.replace( new RegExp( specialthings.join( "|" ), "g" ), "" ) );
console.log( output );
```